# Laravel - Change error message for Authenticates user

Tags: laravel, authentication, backend, credentials, laravel-7

I changed login condition as per my requirement in `AuthenticatesUsers`

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['is_approved' => 1]);
}
```

But for Not Approved error message is **These credentials do not match our records.**

How to change this message?

Comment: if you do a text search for that string "These credentials ..." you will find it in a language file

Comment: Yes but its for error, if credentials doesn't match.

Comment: "How to change this message?", you change it in that file

Answer (score -1):

did you mean validations?? you can change it using the **novalidation**. just insert that at the end of the form. if it does not work, you can use a js.

here's a sample js:

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("form[name='Cust_Form']").validate({
      errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        postal_code: {
            number: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 4,
            required: true
            },
        email: {
            email: true
              },    
        unit: {
            number: true
                },   
         building: {
            number: true
                },   
        contact_2: {
            number: true,
            minlength: 11,
            maxlength: 11
        },
        contact_1: {
            number: true,
            minlength: 11,
            maxlength: 11
        }
      },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
        postal_code: {
            minlength: "Your postal code must be at least 4 characters long",
            number: "Please enter a valid postal code",
            maxlength: "Your postal code must be at least 4 characters long",
            required:  "Required field"
            },
        email: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },  
        unit: {
            number: "Please enter a valid unit number"
                },   
        building: {
            number: "Please enter a valid building/house number"
                },  
        contact_1: {
            minlength: "Your contact number must be at least 11 characters long",
            number: "Please enter a valid contact number",
            maxlength: "Your contact number must be at least 11 characters long"
        },
        contact_2: {
            minlength: "Your contact number must be at least 11 characters long",
            number: "Please enter a valid fax/phone number",
            maxlength: "Your contact number must be at least 11 characters long"
        },
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```